# basics to create a MML console in Python

Tags: python, linux, console, ipc, inter-process-communicat

I am looking to have a MML (man machine language) console written in Python as the only entry point to control and monitor a back-end process. Basically will be able to:

- attach to an existing back-end process
- if back-end process is not running, still open console and be able to spawn back-end process (by introducing the correct command)
- auto-complete permitted commands
- be able to change back-end process behavior based on the introduced commands

What would be the best way to achieve this? How to communicate the back-end process with a console that can be opened and closed without killing the back-end process, by this I mean that the console would not be the parent of that process.

Needs to be written in Python and will run on a CentOS, maybe some OS tools can help to communicate processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High on my list would be [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com). It's fairly easy to build a an [interactive console](http://www.oluyede.org/blog/2008/08/31/twisted-interactive-console/) with and it's [Perspective Broker](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/pb-intro.html) system would probably work well for you. Plus it's very robust, has a fast event loop, and it's very robust.

You could also use the [cmd](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html) module, which was recently featured on Doug Hellmann's excellent site [Python Module of the Week (PyMOTW)](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/cmd/).

For interprocess communication, [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/intro%3aread-the-manual) is fairly easy to work with, and it's very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a start: http://code.google.com/p/squires/wiki/SquiresHowto

You could use a Socket to do the communication between Front- and Backend.

Comment: Squires does look pretty neat.